# adding <script> to WordPress in <head> automatically

Tags: javascript, wordpress, head

I want that the javascript code, run/load for a day (in the head), only on Monday Wednesday Friday automatically and automatically deactivate.
How can I do this?
My idea is to run/load only a few days, an advertisement that is in javascript.
Thank you very much and excuse my English.
Regards

Comment: Turn the problem around. The script is always there but early on on the script, detect the day of the week and then execute the rest of the code as required based on this.

Comment: @Donovan Please share your tried code here. So we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a small function inside functions.php that will enqueue your script based on the day of the week. Something like:

```
function myFunc(){
    $todaysDay = intval(date('N')); // 'N' returns current day as number we convert it to int 
    // we check if it's Monday(1) or Wednesday(3)
    if($todaysDay === 1 || $todaysDay === 3){  
    //if yes enqueue our script
        wp_enqueue_script( 'myJs', get_theme_root_uri() . '/my_theme/path_to_myFile/myJs.js', array(), false);
    } 
}
add_action( 'init', 'myFunc' );
```